# Different methodologies of building indices

Tags: fixed-income, finance, bond, index, etf

Say have a basket of coupon bonds $B_i$ with $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$. Those bonds have different characteristics one from another. For example they differ in maturity, face value and coupon outstanding. But they are in same currency.

The problem I am facing is quite theoretical: how can I come up with a benchmark index of those bonds. In particular, I want to find the "yield" of the index which is composition of all $n$ bonds.

The most trivial thing I could think of is the following ($P_i$ is the $i$-th bond price in 100s, $F_i$ its outstanding face):

1. For each bond I calculate YTM$_i$
2. I define weights as: $w_i = \frac{F_i \cdot P_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^nP_i}$
3. I define YTM of the index as YTM$_I = \sum_{i = 1}^n$YTM$_i \cdot w_i$

Basically a weighted average of YTM. To me, this doesn't have so much theoretical background and may lead to misleading results. Does anybody have any idea on a way to find YTM of the basket of bond (possibly computationally efficient).

Comment: Index yield is non-intuitive. Take a look at https://research.ftserussell.com/products/downloads/FTSE_Fixed_Income_Index_Guide_to_Calculation_new.pdf section 2.4.

Comment: This actually helps a lot! Can you recommend other similar sources (maybe more detailed ones, with some theoretical background)?

Comment: Can also be interesting to know different weights mechanism available out there!

Comment: As I recall, Citi/YieldBook had a good writeup on the theoretical underpinnings of a bond index yield, so so did Merrill Lynch, but I don't see either one posted online, and don't actually have them.

Comment: Not sue of this is one of the docs mr. vulis is referring to https://financedocbox.com/75903663-Mutual_Funds/Ice-bofaml-indices-bond-index-guide.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! These sources really help me getter a better understanding!!